# OpenGL 2d Image Drawing (Java)

Tags: java, opengl

I want to make a simple 2d image that displays whenever something happens. And if statement or whatsoever. Only, how would I do this in OpenGL?

Comment: Java is my favourite programming language. I love it. But I would try doing it in opengl with c/c++ , because I couldnt get jogl (java opengl) to work on my Ubuntu. For C I have a fine base to do what you want.

Comment: Well, thanks for your help but im doing this ontop of minecraft. And minecraft is made in java. (no not a minecraft mod)

Comment: Im trying to do something a bit like minecraft in c. But its going to take a long time...

Comment: Although, porting code should be easy. The commands are exactly the same in Java and Jogl as in c and opengl , so if I would give you some c code it should work in java to, but the framework would have to be a bit different.

Comment: Yeah sure i'll happiliy take that :)

Comment: Thank you. But as I said, it will take some time.

Comment: That's totally okay :)

Comment: @user7185318 You should try LWJGL, which also minecraft uses for its OpenGL bindings. Version 2 of the library is a little more straightforward when you get started.

Regarding this question, in OpenGL, you draw something, or you don't. Every frame has to be built up from specifying which buffers to draw. However, Minecraft's  rendering system is not entirely "down on the metal", and has some layers of abstractions so that various optimisations can be made. As such rendering means you will have to go through these additional layers in order to properly draw your scene.

Comment: @Bartvbl Ill have a look at it, but now I got started with c...